# Select the messages with greatest dates

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
   Message Date       sent received
1. msg     12/03/2020  1      2
2. msg     01/02/2020  2      1
3. msg     03/04/2020  1      2
4. msg     03/05/2020  2      1
5. msg     03/12/2019  1      6
6. msg     03/11/2019  6      1
```

This table contains the dates of messages sent between me(id=1) and other users. I want to select latest 
messages between me and others users no matter who sent or received the message(so i can be on the receiver or sender part).

The result should be something like this:

```
   Message Date       sent received
1. msg     03/05/2020  2      1
2. msg     03/12/2019  1      6
```

Comment: Post also your query and describe what errors you are facing with it

Comment: Also specify MySQL version.

Comment: your sample data don't match the expected result. Row 2 in the result should match row 1 in the sample (2020 after 2019 no?)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, message, max(date), sent, received FROM table WHERE sent=1
UNION
SELECT id, message, max(date), sent, received FROM table WHERE received=1
```

should give you the right output (untested).

This answer is based on the description of the ticket since the example data don't give a valid result for the sample data

Comment: Even if this would run (it does not run in MySql 5.7, 8.0), it has nothing to do with the requirement: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=d6e1100caa42a022c303d017f2848d67

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by least(sent, received), greatest(sent, received)
            order by date desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    where 1 in (sent, received)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where 1 in (t.sent, t.received)
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (sent, received) in ((t.sent, t.received), (t.received, t.sent)) 
  and date > t.date
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qE7ox5SvkhLEZw2n9Sbx2H/1).
Results:

```
| Message | Date       | sent | received |
| ------- | ---------- | ---- | -------- |
| 4. msg  | 2020-05-03 | 2    | 1        |
| 5. msg  | 2019-12-03 | 1    | 6        |
```